# Macro to find header in excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I have 2 excel files. Say file A and file B. File A has below data

[image: File A]

File B has below data.

[image: File B]

Now I want that find the data from file B in file A and it should return the header from file A into result field of file B. For eg. file B has Apple then the macro should search the entire file A and give us header name as FRUIT in the result field. Also if it doesnt found the data then it should return not found. Please advise.

Comment: If your dataset is this small I'd simply loop over all cells in file A for eacht instance in file B. However if file A is large you might want to consider using a dictionary.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? SO is not code-writing service, though it looks like one from time to time. [I downvoted because without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for your example i have grouped the 2 file data in single sheet. please see the below snap.

I have created a small UDF to get your required output. Paste the below UDF in Module and you can directly call this from the cell itself.

```
Public Function searchstring(a As Range, b As Range)
    Dim Header As String
    For i = 1 To a.Columns.Count
        If Not a.Columns(i).Find(b) Is Nothing Then
            Header = a.Cells(1, i)
        End If
    Next i
    searchstring = Header
End Function
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**EDIT:**

use Exit For before Endif to get the first match header.

Comment: Thank you so Karthick it worked. Just have 1 thing in concern. Suppose Apple is there in Fruits and also it is there in Fruits1 (not there in fileA) after country column  then it should return the header where it found first i.e. moving from left to right is should return the header where he found it first. In this case it should be Fruits. I thought my sheet has unique records but I have duplicates in columns after country but if it returns the first header where it found the data first then it will be correct.

Comment: @Satya007, if you want to return the first match header, use `Exit For` before `Header = a.Cells(1,i)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help on this.